# What is more efficient? Generate each tr in javascript or in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What is more efficient for a 'live search function'?

On keyup with a little delay is a request made, the records come back in json and I append those on this way:

```
$.ajax({            
            type: "POST",
            url: "/spares/search/getresults",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "val="+ searchval,
            success: function(response){
                if (response.error == false) {

                        $.each(response.result, function(index, value){
                            $(".choosCred").append("<tr class='productChoose'> <td class='hide'>"+ value.id +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ prod_id +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ article +"</td> <td>"+ value.cd_cred +"</td> <td >"+ value.name_org +"</td> <td >"+ value.quality +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ article_description +"</td> <td>" + '<button type="button" id="add"class="btn-xs btn btn-info add">Add </button>' +"</td> </tr>");         
                        }); 
                }  
            }
        });
```

But I can generate the full table in php and then append it like this:

```
 $.ajax({            
            type: "POST",
            url: "/spares/search/getresults/",
            data: "SearchTerm="+ searchValue,
            success: function(response){
                $(".products tbody").html(response).show();
            }
        });
```

NOTE: In the php code I loop through each result and add some values to it, than i generate there the table because I have already a for loop. When I append this it is lightning fast. When I append the records with javascript and loop through each json result it is slower.

What is the best and fasted way to do it? Or is there another trick to do this?

Comment: The second approach will make your browser hang if there are high number of records.

Comment: Obviously it is better to reduce the response weight, so doing so in javascript make more sense

Comment: On keyup? So what if user pastes text to input using context menu?! Dont forget to handle it too

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes on keyup, pasting content in the search box is not a problem

Comment: Don't pass a string as data. Pass a `{val: searchval}` object instead. Otherwise you need to take care of urlencoding the value properly.

Comment: If you are into object oriented programming the post-request-get pattern with php can make it faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here maybe a minor improvement on your javascript example:

```
$.ajax({            
    type: "POST",
    url: "/spares/search/getresults",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "val="+ searchval,
    success: function(response){
        if (response.error == false) {
            var _content = "";
            $.each(response.result, function(index, value){
                _content += "<tr class='productChoose'> <td class='hide'>"+ value.id +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ prod_id +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ article +"</td> <td>"+ value.cd_cred +"</td> <td >"+ value.name_org +"</td> <td >"+ value.quality +"</td> <td class='hide'>"+ article_description +"</td> <td>" + '<button type="button" id="add"class="btn-xs btn btn-info add">Add </button>' +"</td> </tr>";         
            }); 

            $(".choosCred").append(_content);
        }  
    }
});
```

Now jQuery doesn't need to lookup every single iteration and inject the HTML. Instead do it once.

I think your approach is depending on what the resultset you except to be on how much. Because how more HTML your returning in your request how longer it takes for the javascript to read it/parse it.

For example if you except the return the result set to have 200+ items. It has to parse maybe over 1MB of body/HTML. And you can except it to take a little bit longer. 
But if your results sets are round 10-20 its quicker to push the generated HTML directly into your page.

Hope you understand where Im going with it.

Had lately same problem, because my javascript tried to parse 5MB of HTML. After investigating it took the browser 5-10 seconds to parse the response, while the PHP was done within 150-200ms. I changed to JSON and parsing with javascript and it was done under 1 sec(note: and I added even funky transitions to make it look cool and fast).

Comment: I have 100 Items, and I have a loop in the php to append some values to the array. So the better approach is to send it in json to the client and there i append it with your code?

Comment: Yep, to keep the response a small as possible, only the necessary data to create you result.

Comment: I have tested your example, and it is lightning fast! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is realy depending on the usecase.

We use Ajax to reduce the HTML overhead from a postback. This means you only exchange data (with json for example). With this in mind, you fist aproach is the "better" one.

Performance is a point that can very differ. How good is your server? How good are your Clients? How big are the data? What I can say for sure, if you create the table on the client, your server has less to do (which means can handle more requests).

Answer (score -2):

javaScript way is good because you have to change you value every time user input so javaScript will give better user experience than php

Comment: Okay, but my experience is when I generate it in php the speed is faster than with javascript.

Comment: @da1lbi3, yes in server side(php ) is faster than the client side while loading the data dynamically.

Comment: @user3040610 I have added a note with my use case what is than the fastest way to do? Generate it in php because there is already a for loop, or send json back and loop through it in javascript?

Comment: @da1lbi3,to load faster you can generate in php.

Comment: You experiencing this on your local machine but when you host your file on server javaScript will perform better than PHP code